# How to understand the Network Transmit Interval Steps in the Mesh Spec 4.2.19.2?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, mesh-network, bluetooth-mesh

The ***Network Transmit Interval Steps*** is defined in the Mesh Specification 4.2.19.2:

> The Network Transmit Interval Steps field is a 5-bit value
> representing the number of 10 millisecond steps that controls the
> interval between message transmissions of Network PDUs originating
> from the node.

Does ***Network Transmit Interval Steps***, defined in Mesh Specification 4.2.19.2, represent the ***BLE advertising interval***, defined in *BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 5.0 | Vol 2, Part E, 7.8.5 LE Set Advertising Parameters Command*?

Is there any relationship between them?